# ExtJS - Unable to locate supported Framework

Tags: extjs

Downloaded Ext JS Enterprise* Edition for MacOS Catalina. Unzipped the file and executed the SenchaCmd-7.2.0.66-osx.app which installed the CMD tool.

The instructions to generate the application documented [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_with_zip.html) states the following:

Generate the application using the following command:
sencha -sdk /path/to/downloaded/sdk generate app modern MyApp ./MyApp

what is the /path/to/downloaded/sdk?

Tried several different paths but always get the following error:
Unable to locate 'framework.dir' property from sencha.cfg and no framework directory specified
[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework directory
[ERR] No Framework specified.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could not get the zip download and CMD to work. Used the NPM option to download and make new app.